# Change csv file externally on run time, and doesn't see any effect

Tags: c#, csv, file, streamreader, using

I have a method which reads from a csv file.
The stream reader is being closed due to Using.

I change the csv file externally (Just open the csv file in
Visual studio, change some text, and save it).

I change the file AFTER the Using was ended.
It means the stream supposed to be disposed by now.

Then the same method is being called again, but of some reason,
I get only the old data. The changes had no effect..

Why don't I get the new data?

This is the code:

```
    public async override Task<List<StockData>> GetListOfStockDataFromSource( )
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(_csvFileName))
        using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        {
            csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvSourceMap>();
            List<StockData> stocksAsList = csvReader.GetRecords<StockData>().ToList();

            return stocksAsList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to close your Stream?

Comment: Doesn't it what the "Using" do?

Comment: It should. But I would give it a try. Because your file is stil accessed. :) You could also use external Sysinternal tools to check which process is accessing your file.

Comment: You can force CsvReader and StreamReader to leave the stream open, however this i not specified and would be a bug by the way the code is written, either that or some other process has the file open you are not aware of.. My guess is the later

Comment: @TheGeneral  You were right and I edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code - are you sure you are editing the correct file? A common mistake would be editing the file in your project-directory whereas your application reads it from the bin-directory (in case you are using relative paths).

Comment: @Compufreak Yes, If i edit the file in bin-directory, it works. Thank you. Why doesn't it work when I change the file in Visual studio? In the properties section, the property "Copy to output directory is set to "Copy always". Shouldn't the new file be copied to the Bin directory by Visual Studio?

Comment: The file will be copied on every new build of your project. It will not be copied if you change it without rebuilding your project.

Comment: I added a bit more detailed explanation as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy to output directory` option in Visual Studio only copies files when you build / rebuild your project.

If you want to change the file without rebuilding you need to change the file in the output-directory of your application (usually `bin/{runtimeversion}`). But be aware that those changes will be overwritten on the next rebuild.

Another option would be to use a file path that you can pass as an optional startup parameter. So in your launch settings you can point to the file in your solution directory while debugging whereas your deployed application uses the file in the application directory by default.

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks.